For whom was the Tower of Babel built?
The descendants of Noah, who are the only survivors of the Flood, said:

Come, let us build ourselves a city, and a tower with its top in the sky.  [Gen. 11:4]

Or HaChaim [on Gen. 11:1], from 18th-century Morocco, comments:

Why did they say "We will build a city for ourselves"?  Who else was there to build a city for?

A very pertinent question.  He does not answer it.  Nothing in the Torah is superfluous.  So what is the answer?
(God told Abram "Lech lecha -- Go for yourself", which the Sages interpreted as "Go for your own benefit".  But there the benefit to Abram was not at all obvious to him, so 'lecha' needed to be said.  But here?)

There was not nobody else! There were all the future generations. They would see the city and tower and remember the generation in question

Where is the quote by the Or HaChayyim from?

@RabbiKaii -- If so, then "for ourselves" should be added to every decision.  It isn't.

@MauriceMizrahi every decision where they are doing something for themselves*. Also the Torah doesn't need to do it every time, for instance this "for ourselves" could be simply a reference to lech lecha for the sake of contrast? For eg

@MauriceMizrahi I don't see any commentary on 11:11 (e.g. here on Sefaria), is the verse right? Or which edition are you using?

@b a -- Sorry -- Gen. 11:1

@MauriceMizrahi I still don't see it there, are you using a different edition?

@b a -- See https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Who%20else%20was%20there%20to%20build%20a%20city%20for&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

@MauriceMizrahi You're right, it appears in the translation, but the translation isn't right. The words are ועוד מה הוא כוונת הכתוב שכתב לנו ענין בנין העיר בפרטים המגונים, והלא ארז"ל כי מרצון ה' היה שיתעסקו בבנין העולם - "What does the Torah mean by describing the building of the city as one of the blameworthy details? Didn't the rabbis say God wanted them to build the world?"

What a great question/insight you have noticed. Yes, it does seem superfluous/unnecessary for the humans to say they will build a city for themselves, because afterall, who else would they build it for?
For me that statement is rather a reflection that mankind is no longer interested in following God's orders. God created the earth, all the plants and animals, created a beautiful garden, created humans and asked humans to protect the gardens and to be a ruler/caretaker of all the animals.
We blow it in the garden. We are no longer obligated to guard the garden. Now we will be farmers, but we are still obligated to be fruitful and multiply, to bring positive human dominion over the whole Earth like God commanded. We were not bringing this positive human dominion over the Earth, so God flooded the Earth and restored Noah to being a ruler over animals, saving most of the animals, and allowing noah and his descendants to eat animals in ritually acceptable way after the flood. If Noah's descendants had continued to be farmers (grapes/wine anyone?) and leaders of the animals then all would have been good.
Instead, the tower of Babel is humanity deciding not to expand and rule over the whole Earth like God asked. Rather, they asked themselves what they wanted, and the answer was a city with a tower that reached toward heaven. Humanity had chosen to replace God's desires, with humans desires, which was always the risk of the tree of knowledge of good and evil. They wanted safety and security, they wanted houses, and a tower that might reach toward God. And so their statement of let us build a city for ourselves, reads to me as "let us not fill the earth and subdue it [like God commanded], let us not rule over the animals [in the wild as God commanded]. Rather, let us build a [safe] city, not for God, but for ourselves, and build a tower that reaches to the heavens."

So "for ourselves" means "as opposed to following God's orders"?  The Rashbam said that their sin was in not fulfilling God’s basic directive to be fruitful and multiply, and populate the whole earth, not just a small valley. Since their declared objective was not to scatter, the fact that God forcefully scattered them afterwards shows that their sin must have been their failure to do so voluntarily.

Yes that is my interpretation. I'm glad my opinion is in good company with the Rashbam. Thank you for letting me know the Rashbam's interpretation

@MauriceMizrahi The only difference between your presentation of the Rashbam and myself is the dominion over the animals is also part of the package. The Bible seems to assume we would continue domesticating, protecting, teaching and breeding animals as part of our dominion over the whole earth. When I see people teaching rats to clear out land mines, dogs to find people under collapsed buildings, baboons to act as shepherds, etc, those people are carrying out God's proposed animal dominion.

Midrash makes Nimrod the king who built the tower. He made the people believe that he was merely the "first citizen" or the like and that after the people built the tower and killed God, the people, free of His tyrany, could live in a egalitarian society. The slogan was "for ourselves" to distract from Nimrod's probably planning on taking power himself.

Exactly, the oldest form of socialism/communism - everything belongs to the state! Did not Nimrod's grandson build a statue of Nimrod which became representative of their idol Bel afterwards?
